# Is it possible to execute a function or command at a specific time?

Tags: elisp, timers

Is it possible to execute a function or command at a specific time? As an  explicit example, is it possible to kill emacs at a specific time (time determined by the OS).

Comment: See also [midnight-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MidnightMode)

Comment: I see someone is taking hard measure to prevent emacs addiction :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to use the function `run-at-time`, described in Chapter 38.10 of the Emacs Lisp manual.  In your case, something like this should do the trick:

```
(run-at-time "20:30" nil #'kill-emacs)
```

If the function you want to call takes parameters, you can specify them as additional parameters to `run-at-time`:

```
(run-at-time "5 sec" nil #'message "Tempus volat, hora fugit.")
```

Note that absolute times are taken to be today, even if they are in the past, so the first example above will exit immediately if it is after 20:30.

Comment: I put your code it in my .emacs file. It kills emacs at the given time! But when I restart emacs, it is immediately killed. Any hint?

Comment: @Name edited to clarify.

Comment: LOL, you can start with the -q switch to bypass the init file that'll be toasting your emacs until midnight.  Then the glass slipper falls and you can edit again until that same time tomorrow.