# Conditional run-at-time to update elfeed

Tags: timers, elfeed

I run Emacs in daemon mode on my Virtual Private Server and use [elfeed](https://github.com/skeeto/elfeed/) along with `elfeed-web` to manage my RSS feeds and make them available at a basic but convenient web-page I can visit and browse recent posts.

This works well but I'd like to update the feeds automatically and am trying to use [`run-at-time`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/6029/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-function-or-command-at-a-specific-time) to do so.

I've a small function to make sure the elfeed database is loaded from disk and up-to-date before updating and saving.

```lisp
(defun ns:elfeed-updater ()
  "Wrapper to load the elfeed db from disk before opening"
  (interactive)
  (elfeed-db-save)
  (quit-window)
  (elfeed-db-load)
  (elfeed)
  (elfeed-search-update--force)
  (elfeed-update))
  (elfeed-db-save)
```

I can call this function manually and it updates my feeds.

I share my Emacs config across systems so I have the following config that I hope restricts the `run-at-time` to that of my vps. I want to not only set the time but for it do repeat twice a day so I set the `repeat` in the call to `(* 12 3600)` as per the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html#index-run_002dat_002dtime) which says this value is the number of seconds between repeat calls.

```lisp
(use-package elfeed
  :ensure t
  :config
  ;; run-with-timer takes an argument in seconds
  (if system-name "vps-id" (run-at-time "07:00" (* 12 3600) 'ns:elfeed-update))
  (setq elfeed-web-enabled t)
  :hook
  (ns:elfeed-updater . elfeed-web-start))

(use-package elfeed-web
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq httpd-port 8818))
```

Unfortunately the feed doesn't seem to update and I have to manually go in and update it every few days.  If I look at `list-timers` its not listed...

```
Idle           Next       Repeat Function
               6.0s         5.0s auto-revert-buffers
               8.5s            - undo-auto--boundary-timer
              10.9s           1m ac-clear-variables-every-minute
              30.7s           1h url-cookie-write-file
              53.3s           5m savehist-autosave
 *           0.1s            t highlight-indent-guides--try-update-line-cache
 *           0.1s            t show-paren-function
 *           0.5s            t #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x12c7c0860a2e63de> [jit-lock--antiblink-grace-timer jit-lock-context-fontify])
 *           1.0s            t which-key--update
 *           1.0s       repeat ess--idle-timer-function
```

I can't work out what I've done wrong, the `system-name` I'm comparing against is definitely correct.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: You mean `(if (string= system-name "vps-id") ...` - and you should probably use `when` instead of `if` since tehre is no `else` clause.

Comment: Thanks @NickD, I'd not come across `when` before and this shows I really need to find the time to learn (e)Lisp better. If you want to add this as answer I'll happily accept it. I did some checking though and whilst `(string= system-name "vps-id")` evaluates to `nil` on systems other than `vps-id` the timer is still started with `(when (string= system-name "vps-id" (run-at-time "07:00" (* 12 3600) 'elfeed-update))`  which surprised me (not necessarily a problem as I can kill the timer).

Comment: You are missing (at least) one paren: `(when (string= system-name "vps-id") (run-at-time "07:00" (* 12 3600) 'elfeed-update))`, so I suspect you have a typo.

Comment: Clumsy re-typing on my behalf, I should have copy and pasted. Just tried evaluating it again and its not added it to `*timer-list*` (I suspect that, like most of my problems, this is down to something sitting between the keyboard and screen and last time I evaluated something slightly different).